# Discord bot does not run

Tags: javascript, discord.js

my code is as following

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");

const config = require("./Data/config.json");

const intents = new Discord.Intents(32767);

const client = new Discord.Client({ intents });

client.on("ready", () => console.log("Bot is online!"));

client.login(config.token);
```

and it is returning me this error, may I know what is wrong? Thanks

```
PS C:\Users\shiyu\Desktop\Programming\Tutorial Bot> node .
C:\Users\shiyu\Desktop\Programming\Tutorial Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\APIRequest.js:33
    agent ??= new https.Agent({ ...this.client.options.http.agent, keepAlive: true });
          ^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '??='
?[90m    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:988:16)?[39m
?[90m    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1036:27)?[39m
?[90m    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1101:10)?[39m
?[90m    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:937:32)?[39m
?[90m    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:12)?[39m
?[90m    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:961:19)?[39m
?[90m    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:92:18)?[39m
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\shiyu\Desktop\Programming\Tutorial Bot\node_modules\?[4mdiscord.js?[24m\src\rest\RESTManager.js:4:20)
?[90m    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1072:14)?[39m
?[90m    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1101:10)?[39m
```

Not sure why this code is not working as I am following a guide. I have checked everything many times and yeah regardless of what I do it returns me an error. The require did find the discord.js module this is for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrade your Node.js. The version you're using does not support the `??` operator.

Discord.js requires ([as per their documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/general/welcome)) Node.js 16.6 or newer.